How to create db on fly and read azure ad setting if available else to show the form to user to add details
I have configuration reading in my program class as below
if (azureAdSettings != null)
{
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"] = azureAdSettings.Instance;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"] = azureAdSettings.Domain;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] = azureAdSettings.TenantId;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"] = azureAdSettings.ClientId;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"] = azureAdSettings.ClientSecret;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(azureAdSettings?.ClientId))
    {
        string[] scopes = builder.Configuration["Graph:Scopes"].Split(",");
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(scopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    }
}

Is there any way to check here if (azureAdSettings != null) if db is already created. The issue is the custom middleware is throwing issue at this line here return context?.AzureAdSettings?.FirstOrDefault();
This is complete Program.cs file
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
});

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(o =>
{
    o.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
        new CultureInfo("ar-QA")
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-GB", uiCulture: "en-GB");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        sqlOptions =>
        {
            sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
        });
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o =>
{
    o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
    {
        return factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
    };
});

builder.Services.AddSession();

builder.Services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    options.OnPermissionCheck = context => context.User.IsInRole("BusinessAdmin");
});

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDBContext>();
        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
        await DbInitializer.SeedData(context, services);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration and seeding");
    }
}

// Load Azure AD settings
var azureAdSettings = StartupHelper.LoadAzureAdSettings(builder.Configuration);

if (azureAdSettings != null)
{
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"] = azureAdSettings.Instance;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"] = azureAdSettings.Domain;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] = azureAdSettings.TenantId;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"] = azureAdSettings.ClientId;
    builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"] = azureAdSettings.ClientSecret;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(azureAdSettings?.ClientId))
    {
        string[] scopes = builder.Configuration["Graph:Scopes"].Split(",");
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(scopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    }
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/AccessDenied");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseMiddleware<AzureAdSettingsMiddleware>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(azureAdSettings?.ClientId))
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}

app.UseElmah();

var options = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

And this is my custom middleware where the error is coming.
    public class AzureAdSettingsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public AzureAdSettingsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ApplicationDBContext dbContext, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var settings = await dbContext.AzureAdSettings.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (settings == null && !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Settings/Setup"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Settings/Setup");
                return;
            }
            else if (settings != null && !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Settings/AdSetupComplete"))
            {
                var azureAdClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                if (azureAdClientId != settings.ClientId)
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Append("X-Message", "Your AD is set up. Please restart the application");
                    var redirectUrl = "/Settings/AdSetupComplete?redirected=true";
                    context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
                    return;
                }
            }
            await _next(context);
        }
    }

    public class StartupHelper
    {
        public static AzureAdSettings LoadAzureAdSettings(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDBContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

            using (var context = new ApplicationDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                return context.AzureAdSettings.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }

And this is my db initilizer file complete https://pastebin.com/H7XC68Pv. Is there any way to check db is created befor reading settings from db, else i am promting user to enter their creds. Thanks!
